# Attractive and repulsive fixed points

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the function $f(x) = ax(1-x)$. I have to show that if $ 1 < a < 3$ that the fixed point $p_2 = \dfrac{a-1}{a}$ is attractive, and if $ 3 < a < 4$ it is repulsive.

I actually have no idea how to do this. I found that the top of the function is at $ ( \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{a}{4} )$ and I have found that $f'(0) = a$ and $f'(\dfrac{a-1}{a})  = 2-a$, but I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 4):

Your function is a ['logistic map'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) and the trick is to compare $|f'(p_2)|$ to $1$. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29#Attractive_fixed_points) he have indeed :
"If the function $f$ is continuously differentiable in an open neighbourhood of a fixed point $x_0$, and $|f'(x_0)|<1$, attraction is guaranteed."

This link to Wikipedia's picture may give you an intuitive explication (warning the vertical scale is a little too elongated). The iterations start at $x=-1$ and clearly converge at the right : now let's suppose that the vertical line at the right would go down a little more (supposing that the slope is steeper with $\ f'(x_0)<-1\ $) then we would go farther than we were at the top and go away from the limit instead of approaching as we do here (the spiral would be divergent).

[image: linked wikipedia picture]

You found $\ f'\left(\dfrac{a-1}{a}\right)  = 2-a$

But for $\ 1<a<3\ $ we have $\ 2-3<2-a<2-1\ $ and obtain that 
$\ \left|f'\left(\dfrac{a-1}{a}\right)\right|<1$

The repulsive part will be handled the same way.

Btw Wikipedia has a nice animation when the value of $a$ changes.
[image: animation]

Comment: Re the quote from Wikipepdia: I believe we can replace "continuously differentiable" with "differentiable", and the same result holds, since we have $-1<\dfrac{f(x)-p}{x-p}<1$ for $x$ in a symmetric neighborhood of $p$, so long as we choose it small enough.

Comment: @EricAuld: Consider $f(x):=2\,x^2\,\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ else. The (discontinuous) derivative will oscillate wildly between $-2$ and $2$ near $0$.

Comment: I agree that the derivative will oscillate wildly (though it will stay bounded); however, $\dfrac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\leq \rho < 1$ in a neighborhood of zero (by definition of the derivative), and that proves that $0$ is an attractive fixed point.

Comment: @EricAuld: I'll admit your use of the differentiability to prove that we have a contraction mapping.
My point was that the inequality $\,|f'(x)|<1$ could have been wished for a neighborhood of the fixed point $x_0$ (no such neighborhood exists in my example) even if not required explicitely by Wikipedia's sentence.
This comment can't be a substitute to a discussion at Wikipedia but I can imagine different reasons to suppose class $C^1$ : the fixed point is searched (not supposed known) so that a finite interval is wanted to apply the theorem, the fixed point doesn't admit a closed form,

Comment: we are using fixed precision (and obtain an infinity of 'nearly solutions' in my example !), Wikipedia could suppose a specific context (there are many fixed points theorems), other stability issues could be important (additional parameter(s)), the problem could be a physicist's one (their functions are usually supposed analytic or distributions) and so on...